# Make my textbox understand html img tag

Tags: javascript, html

When inserting a new emoji inside my textbox i want to be displayed as the emoji image and not the emoji symbol how can i do that like instead of ( `':)'`--> put the image represent it inside my textbox )

Comment: If your "textbox" is a <textarea> tag, it's impossible. You'll have to use a js lib to generate a more complex markup.

Comment: I'd consider using an existing rich text editor library, one might already support this out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use images, then it would require you to change your HTML significantly. You would need to make use of the [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable) functionality on something like a `<span>`, rather than a regular input box. You'd then need JavaScript code to monitor keypress events and whenever it sees a `:)` (or whatever), it replaces the code with the appropriate `<img>`.

A quick-and-dirty solution that sticks with your text box, however, would be to use the same approach, but use the [Unicode emoji characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_in_the_Unicode_standard) (rather than images). This will only work on platforms with the appropriate font glyphs -- although the common smilies are more widely supported -- but it gives you the idea:

HTML:

```
<input class="emojify" type="text" />
```

JavaScript (using jQuery, to make everyone's life easier):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Map plaintext smilies to Unicode equivalents
  var emoji = {
                ':)': '\u263a',
                ':(': '\u2639'
              },

      // Function to escape regular expressions
      reEscape = function(s) {
                   return s.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
                 };

  $('input.emojify').keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();

    // See if any of our emoji exist in the text and replace with Unicode
    $.each(emoji, function(plaintext, unicode) {
       text = text.replace(new RegExp(reEscape(plaintext), 'g'), unicode);
    });

    // Replace text with new values
    $(this).val(text);
  });
});
```

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EJJuM/) on jsFiddle. Note that the caret position will be reset every time the `keyup` event is triggered. I'm sure you can work around that somehow, but this code suffices to illustrate the process.

Comment: @user254153 They're all listed in the Wikipedia article I linked to in my answer

Answer (score 4):

One way: Instead of a text box, use a `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`.  As the user types, change occurrences of the smiley for the image. When the form is submitted, your javascript needs to translate the contents of that div back into plain text and put it into a field for submission.