# How to add emojis in a textbox in html

Tags: html

Hi I want to try and add emojis to my html5 textbox I tried to to something like this `<input type="text" emoji>` and also like this `<input type="emoji">` but it still does not work

if anyone could help that would be great

Comment: What do you mean by "add emojis"? They're just characters. You can put them anywhere. (And, for that matter, what is an "html5 textbox"? It's just an input. Nothing to do with HTML5 in particular.)

Answer (score 1):

check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359508/make-my-textbox-understand-html-img-tag)

And if you want to create a box to select the emoji, just use the [Emoji-picker](https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker).

Answer (score 0):

Another picker is available at https://github.com/DigiLive/EmojiPopper

This one utilizes the popper component of bootstrap 4 without altering/replacing the original html element.